# iOS Simulator interface blurry in Xcode 6 GM iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios8

I've been testing my apps under the iOS 8 Simulator in Xcode 6 GM but for some weird reason, the app interface is displaying blurry, like its been slightly zoomed. Even the status bar is zoomed in the same way.

Edit: When the Launch Image loads, the zoom is correct and everything including the status bar is sharp, but then once the app loads fully, everything zooms.

Has anyone else noticed this or have a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: On iOS Simulator app, is Window -> Scale less than 100%? Or are you using a low-res monitor and the simulator is huge on the screen? I've been using the XC6 GM and haven't seen (or heard of) these problems..

Comment: Window > Scale is 100%. I'm running a 27in iMac and never had these issues under earlier versions of the Xcode betas.

Comment: have you added launch images for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus? because otherwise ios scales your app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you have not added launch images for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus. In that case ios 8 opens app in scale mode. Just add them through catalog assets.

Comment: of course! I can't believe I missed that.. thanks :)