# Blurry UI elements in ios8 iPhone6/6+

Tags: objective-c, iphone, user-interface, optimization, ios8

I noticed a lot of apps seem rather "blurry" on the new iphone 6/6s. How do we optimize our code/storyboard so that when the app runs on newer devices, it doesn't look like it was upscaled?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781920/ios-simulator-interface-blurry-in-xcode-6-gm-ios-8/25782423#25782423 the same question

Comment: Ah i saw that and thought it was an simulator issue. I added new launch images already and nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

You need to either include properly sized launch images or change the project to use Launch NIB file where you design launch view.

[image]

Select Don't use asset catalog and create a NIB file instead. This way launch view will be auto-layout and compatible with any device resolution.

Comment: I added new launch images for both the 6 and 6+ but the app looks the same as it did before. Not sure what you mean by the latter